# UIKit and unit testing

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode

I'm tying to implement some test cases for my iPhone app. I have successfully set up the UnitTest-Target as described here: [iPhone development guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html)

I'm also able to build a simple test case:

`- (void) testPass {

    STAssertTrue(TRUE, @"");

}`

But when I'm trying to instantiate a class that has some methodes that return UIColors the test fails:

`@interface BCGlobals : NSObject {

}

+(BCGlobals*)instance;

-(UIColor*) redTextColor;

-(UIColor*) greenTextColor;

@end`

The error message is: 'UIColor' undeclared (first use in this function)

Is it possible, that I cannot test classes referring to UIKit within a logic test in XCode?

Comment: It looks like when I'm building the test case target, the linker does not linkt the UIKit framework correctly. Even if I add it expicitly to the test target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

?

Comment: In the test case: SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h and UIKit/UIKit.h In the tested class: Foundation/Foundation.h

Comment: I don't know if you copy pasted the code but the second method should be 
- (UIColor *) redTextColor;

Comment: Corrected that, thanks... seems like stackOverflow is interpretating the * as an enumeration...

Comment: Ok, now I've added the UIKit import to the tested class. And it works. But why? I do not need the import at all if I'm only building the iPhone app. Why do I need this additional import only in the case of a test case build?