# Test case failing at [[MyObject alloc] init]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, unit-testing

I have a subclass of UITextView that conforms to UIKeyInput protocol. So I wrote some logic tests.
I have no errors and all other test run well but When myTextView object is supposed to be created:

```
MyTextView *myTextView = [[MyTextView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

the test stops, (like a break point) It won't continue

I wonder why is this?  Perhaps objects of MyTextView cannot be created in logic tests? Do I need an application test here? If that is the case, what is the rule?

**ADDED**:

This is one of the tests: (I have a couple more but all them stop at the first line)

```
    - (void)testHasText{
    MyTextView *myTextView = [[MyTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [myTextView setText:@"some text"];
    STAssertTrue([myTextView hasText], @"hasText failed: It has text!");
    [myTextView setText:@""];
    STAssertFalse([myTextView hasText], @"hasText failed: It it empty!");
    [myTextView release];

}
```

This is the implementation in MyTextView:

```
- (BOOL)hasText{
    return [[self text] length]>0?YES:NO;
}
```

I have commented other methods in MyTextView, only left the three related to UIKeyInput.

Also I have added MyTextView.m to the Compile Source list in LogicTests target. Could this be a configuration issue even though I don't get any Linker Error or warning?

Comment: I think we'll need a lot more detail to help you. Posting the code to your subclass's initWithFrame method, plus the test-case code, would be a start.

Comment: UITextView might be a class cluster, in which case subclassing wouldn't work.

Comment: @Emilio What do you mean by class cluster?

Comment: Some "classes" in the frameworks aren't actually just a class, they are actually a lot of classes working together (NSArray and NSDictionary are examples of that). Apple presents them as a single class so it seems easy to use, but subclassing them can give you headaches :P

Comment: [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide /Class Clusters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34)

Comment: I have subclasses UITextView many times in the past, so maybe is not a cluster? (In the docs they don't say so too), This is just the first time I try to use a subclass of UITextView in a Logic Test, I am very new to Logic tests :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic tests that only run in the test bundles are not able to use UI elements. You need to create an application test for this.

I can recommend taking a look at [FoneMoneky](http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey) by Gorilla Logic for performing UI related tests. It will enable you to also test the actual UI in unit tests.

Comment: So, all UIKit subclasses must be tested in application tests?

Comment: @nacho4d In general, yes. I think there are a few exceptions but can't remember exactly which ones right now. FoneMonkey will however allow you to make faceless UI tests, so it's partly application test partly core unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You've got one reference to `wmTextView`, which doesn't seem to exist. That would be the first thing I'd check.

The second would be this past question: [UIKit and unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177872/uikit-and-unit-testing)

Comment: that reference was just a typo here. :)